# Install Angular on Node 16 get warnings

Tags: node.js, angular

I am installing Angular on Node 16.15.0 or latest LTS and I get the following warnings, should I continue on my project or change the node versions ?

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular/cli@13.3.5',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: {
npm WARN EBADENGINE     node: '^12.20.0 || ^14.15.0 || >=16.10.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6 || >=8.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     yarn: '>= 1.13.0'
npm WARN EBADENGINE   },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.15.0', npm: '7.5.3' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/architect@0.1303.5',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: {
npm WARN EBADENGINE     node: '^12.20.0 || ^14.15.0 || >=16.10.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6 || >=8.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     yarn: '>= 1.13.0'
npm WARN EBADENGINE   },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.15.0', npm: '7.5.3' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/core@13.3.5',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: {
npm WARN EBADENGINE     node: '^12.20.0 || ^14.15.0 || >=16.10.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6 || >=8.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     yarn: '>= 1.13.0'
npm WARN EBADENGINE   },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.15.0', npm: '7.5.3' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/schematics@13.3.5',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: {
npm WARN EBADENGINE     node: '^12.20.0 || ^14.15.0 || >=16.10.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6 || >=8.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     yarn: '>= 1.13.0'
npm WARN EBADENGINE   },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.15.0', npm: '7.5.3' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@schematics/angular@13.3.5',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: {
npm WARN EBADENGINE     node: '^12.20.0 || ^14.15.0 || >=16.10.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6 || >=8.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     yarn: '>= 1.13.0'
npm WARN EBADENGINE   },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.15.0', npm: '7.5.3' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
```

Comment: Is something unclear from the warnings? What is your _question_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's an issue with your npm version and not the node one.
It's expecting npm version > 7.5.6, whereas your npm version is 7.5.3

```
required: {
 ...
 npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6 || >=8.0.0',
},
current: { node: 'v16.15.0', npm: '7.5.3' }
```